# Find Latest Record With Specific Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the row with the latest Date in the group. However, if that row has some specific value in specific column, then we must eliminate the row completely
For Ex in the following table:

```
 ID   FK_ID    DateTiME     Value
  1     1     2017-06-01    a
  2     1     2017-06-02    a
  3     2     2017-06-04    b
  4     2     2017-06-03    a 
  5     2     2017-06-01    b
  6     3     2017-01-01    c
  7     3     2017-01-01    a
```

Here I want the output as

```
FK_ID   DateTime 
  1    2017-06-02
  3    2017-01-01
```

I want to group on `FK_ID` and then want the Max `DateTime` Value from the Group. However, If the selected Row of the Group has `Value` as `b` then we should skip the row entirely and don't want it in the output.

For Example, in the above table(1), the row with Max DateTime for `FK_ID` 2 is

```
  3     2     2017-06-04    b
```

However, as the value for this row is `b`, we don't want it in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use row_number

```
With CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by FK_ID order by datetime desc) rn
from MyTable t1
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
and value <> 'b'
```

Comment: I think is the correct answer out of all 3 assumptions +1 :D

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Because it's possible that a row gets `rn=1` with value=b. For that group you would not get a result. Instead you have to filter the value in the cte. **Edit** maybe i have misunderstood the requirement if i look at the expected result. OP doesn't want to skip the _row_ with value=b but the entire group. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to this

```
select top 1 with ties * 
from yourtable a
where not exists(select 1  from yourtable b where a.FK_ID =b.FK_ID and b.Value = 'b') 
order by row_number()over(partition by FK_ID order by [DateTiME] desc)
```